# How to define $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

Tags: php, linux, apache

I am trying to install a PHP application on a Linux running Apache2 and PHP5.

I noticed that, whenever I try to access the application (for example, hitting the `index.php` file), the browser returns a blank page. Running a `phpinfo()` works fine though.

Through testing, I have realized that the problem lies in the code of the applicatio, which has lost of lines like this one:

`require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/202-config/functions.php');`

If I change this to `require_once('./202-config/functions.php');`, then the application runs ok (at least that part of the application.

If I run a `print_r($_SERVER)`, `DOCUMENT_ROOT` appears empty.

My question for you guys is: as I dont want to go through all the code in this application and replace these `require_once` statements, is there a way to define the value of DOCUMENT_ROOT?

Thanks.

Comment: It would be a good idea to turn on error reporting so your blank page turns into something useful

Comment: Have you tried `require_once(__DIR__ . '/202-config/functions.php');` ?

Comment: Workaround: put `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = __DIR__;` in your `index.php`. `$_SERVER` is a superglobal, this change will affect all subsequent uses.

Answer (score 6):

From the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

> The entries in this array are created by the web server. There is **no** guarantee that every web server will provide any of these;

Also if you run script from command line it might not be set.

Workaround is to set explicitly:

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) || empty($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']))
    $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = __DIR__; //or dirname(__FILE__) for older php verstions
```

**Note:** You use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to include scripts. So it's better idea to rely on constants [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) and [`__FILE__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) rather than `$_SERVER`.

Comment: But will they always be set? i.e. `isset($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])` always return true, so using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] won't error because it's just empty? EDIT: your edit suggests not.

Comment: @popnoodles Did not get your comment. There are two possibilities: 1. there is no such index like `DOCUMENT_ROOT` in `$_SERVER`. 2. There is element with key `DOCUMENT_ROOT` but it's empty. Sample covers both. If there's anything else rephrase your comment, please.

Comment: I was asking "will `isset($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])?` always return true?. However you edited to check for that, instead of leaving your original which would have indicated that it would always be set but may be empty.

Comment: this is funny because when I do debug of __DIR__ it returns me 'xdebug:'

Comment: `__DIR__` returns the directory of the script being executed.  Assigning it to `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is therefore unreliable I think.

Comment: @kzpm This answer is ancient. Back then people were maintaining scripts where includes with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOR']` could be spread across hundreds if not thousands files. Therefore this was the only efficient workaround. And if anyone still maintains that kind of source, I feel really sorry for them. :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have set the `DocumentRoot "/var/www"` in your Apache-Virtualhost-Config? In CLI this field is empty. In that case you can set this value manually:

```
if ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] == '') {
  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = __DIR__;
}
```

or for PHP < 5.2

```
if ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] == '') {
  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = dirname(__FILE__);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also could do something like this:

```
if (empty($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])) {
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = './';
}
```

But this is not a nice way